# How use CSRF with multi part form Not work

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, multer, csrf-protection

Im try build a form to upload images, but when use csrf this donw work for me and, I was reading that need  this code in you form enctype tag:

```html
<form method="post" action="/?_csrf=<%=csrfToken%>">
```

this work for me but if  want save one image only, but if want Edit or Delete, don't work, because use override method ?_method=PUT and return a URl with me CSRF

```html
http://localhost:3030/stories/5bafe7a5abe3a7110c5f386b?_csrf=wkhEeV2x-06M_KPnZRoSTPJ3mUZSnuZ6dl7s

Cannot POST
```

```html
<form class="col s12" action="/stories/{{storieEdit.id}}?_csrf={{csrfToken}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field  col s12">
            <div class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input type="file" name="fileUpload" onchange="previewFile()">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          
                <img src="/uploads/{{storieEdit.image}}" alt="Image" style="width: 25rem;">
               
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

any suggestions

Thanksfor read me

Answer (score 0):

For multiple images you need to add to your form enctype atribute like this: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

For method override you need to add method type as well as csrfToken to action query string: 
`action="/stories/{{storieEdit.id}}?_method=PUT&_csrf={{csrfToken}}"`

I have similar code and works fine.
Bellow you can find the required changes directly in your code.

```html
<form class="col s12" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/stories/{{storieEdit.id}}?_method=PUT&_csrf={{csrfToken}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field  col s12">
            <div class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input type="file" name="fileUpload" onchange="previewFile()">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          
                <img src="/uploads/{{storieEdit.image}}" alt="Image" style="width: 25rem;">
               
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Now this work!! thanks , but i have a question es secure this form pass csrf  token in the url the post.
i was try pass method override Put in url and csrf token in hidden input. and middleware